# Keycloak: Make query string param available in marker FreeMarker template

Tags: java, freemarker, keycloak

Context: using https://www.keycloak.org/ as an authentication provider.

I have a use case where I need to render a block of HTML depending on the value of a query string param in the login page. The value will be coming from the login URL similar to this:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/default/protocol/openid-connect/auth?...&customvar=1
```

I would like to have `customvar` available in the `login.ftl` to accomplish my objective. So far I have tried to retrieve the baseUrl from the client bean, but it’s not available, the app crashes when I attempt to access baseUrl. I have also attempted to access the request url in the `${url}`, but it's not available either.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You could go with javascript and make the evaluation at client side.

Answer (score 2):

try href="${client.baseUrl}" it should return a client baseUrl.